# JSF 2.0 Set default value on page

Tags: java, jsf

I would like to know if there is a way to set a default value to a inputText, or inputHidden or any other tag that can be recovered in the backing bean when the page shows.

I would like something like this (this code doesn't work):

```
<h:inputText id="companyName" value="#{loginController.companyName}" defaultValue="123456">
```

And in the backing bean:

```
private String companyName;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    System.out.println("CompanyName=" + companyName);
}
```

So that it shows "**CompanyName=123456**" in the console.

I need to define the default value in the page itself, I don't want to put the default value in the backing bean.

*The real problem is that I need to find a way to pass a value to the backing bean defined in the page.* I have many pages and I want to define a 'mode' in each page to be shown differently, and this 'mode' needs to be read by the backing bean when the page displays (before any submit)

Comment: How does the page know, in which mode it presents itself? Doesn't the logic should decided that? If so, you've got the value in the logic and should pass it to the backing bean imho.

Comment: @Manuel I want to declare the mode in the page, but I don't know how. For example, in some pages I want a 'selection' mode, so I would like to put something like '<h:inputHidden value="#{bean.mode}" defaultValue="SELECTION"/>' and in the bean, read the value 'SELECTION' in the attribute 'mode'

Comment: You can initialize a field in its declaration, and this is pure java, or in a method annotated with `PostConstruct`. If you want specific behaviour for different views or pages, you can use a different bean for each view.

Comment: @perissf I would like to use a common bean for all the pages, so I can concentrate the logic in a single place. I would like to 'mark' each page with a different mode and read the value in this bean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've somewhat solved the problem by showing what I want to show in certain mode, using an h:panelGroup and an *EL* expression to set the value to the bean:

```
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{loginController.companyName('123456')}" >
...
</h:panelGroup>
```

Thanks everybody for your comments

Comment: The page should not contain too much logic Emiliano. I would move the decision to the bean. Instead of `rendered="#{loginController.companyName('123456')}"` use `rendered="#{loginController.showCompany123456()}"`. Therefore the logic is still in the bean and the page is just for the view.

Comment: It's not a matter of logic. The expression '123456' is different on each page. And I want the same bean for all the pages. That's why it's there and not in the bean